# Удалить все вложенные <p></p> из div перед загрузкой страницы

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить конкретные теги из div, а все остальные неуказанные теги оставить?
Нужно, чтобы это выполнялось до загрузки страницы, потому что использовал detach(), но поисковик успевает загрузить страницу и все, что не нужно, проиндексировать.

Нужно удалить все теги "p" и "h2" с их содержимым в 'div class="block"'

```
<div class="block">
 <p>текст текст
 <p>текст текст
 <p>текст текст
 <p><h2>подзаголовок</h2>
 <table></table>
</div>
```

Как видим, даются теги 'p' без закрывающейся половины. Будет ли это проблемой?
Еще момент. Использую все скрипты в отдельном js-файле, который состоит из:

```
$(function() {

// скрипт галереи
 $(".gallery")...({     
 });

// скрипт слайдера
 $(".slider")...({      
 });

});
```

Простите, не силен в js ((

Comment: const parent = document.querySelector(".block");
parent.querySelectorAll("p, h2").forEach(e => parent.removeChild(e));

Comment: ничего не поменялось

Comment: "поисковик успевает загрузить страницу" - поисковик может грузить страницу без скриптов. В этом случае все ваши усилия тщетны.

Comment: Единственное надежное решение - не передавать лишние данные с сервера на клиент.

Comment: "поисковик может грузить страницу без скриптов." - он загружает со скриптами. в сохраненной копии работают слайдеры и галереии. значит нужен скрипт, который выполняет удаление нужных тегов перед загрузкой страницы.